# compile c++ program eclipse that uses matlab engine

Tags: c++, eclipse, matlab, linker, matlab-engine

I am trying to configure eclipse to compile and run the example `engdemo.cpp`, that uses the matlab engine.

I followed the instructions written [here](http://mindchasers.net/knowledge/matlabengine.html), but I have still errors:

```
make all 
Building target: matlabEngine
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86 -Xlinker -rpath-link -Xlinker /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86 -o"matlabEngine"  ./engdemo.o   -leng -lm -lmat -lmex -lut
/usr/bin/ld: ./engdemo.o: undefined reference to symbol 'mxDestroyArray'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'mxDestroyArray' is defined in DSO /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [matlabEngine] Errore 1
```

When I compile the program from the shell I use these commands, and I have no errors so I can run it.

```
g++ -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/include/cpp -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/include -DGLNX86 -DGCC  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "engdemo.cpp"
g++ -O  -o  "engdemo"  engdemo.o  -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86 -leng -lmx -lm
```

But I need to compile in eclipse. 
Any help?

Comment: It seems libmx is missing from the eclipse command line, did you add that library?

Comment: @Rolle, how do you think the linker knows the name of the .so and the path to the library?

Answer (score 0):

Usually linker errors can be quite nasty to debug. In this case the error is very informative.

`undefined reference to symbol 'mxDestroyArray'` indicates that a library containing the symbol called `mxDestroyArray` is not being linked in. However, it does tell you that the library is called `libmx.so` and is found in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86` so that you know where to look.

In your `g++ -O ...` command, you are including the path to this library (`...  -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86 ...`), which explains why it works.

You also need to reference the library itself in the linker command using the `-l` flag, seen by the `-lmx` in the `g++ -O ...` command.

You need to do the same thing in Eclipse.

In Eclipse, you can find the project paths and symbols by selecting the `Project` menu and going to `Properties`. Expand `C/C++ General` and select `Paths and Symbols`. This dialog allows you to tell Eclipse where the libraries the linker needs are located, similar to the -L parameter in g++.

To do so, add the library name and path to the lists under the `Library Paths` and `Libraries` tabs.

NOTE: Adding the path is not enough, you also need to specify the library name (in g++ it's the -l parameter, in this case, `-lmx`)

On the `Libraries` tab, add a new library called `mx`. This should add a `-lmx` to your eclipse linker command.

Comment: Yes, I have already done this. Infact in the eclipse console the command that it uses shows that the path it's correct: g++ -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86 -Xlinker -rpath-link -Xlinker /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86 -o"matlabEngine"  ./engdemo.o   -leng -lm -lmat -lmex -lut

Comment: yeah, you've included the library path, but not the actual library (identified by the `-lmx`), which is not found in the eclipse build command. I've added a note to my answer to explain this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks! Now the code compiles and links. But when I try to run it says matlab: Command not found.
The matlab command is in my search path infact I can call it from my shell. My here in eclipse console it can't found this command. How do I do to set up it? Thanks for the support